# Dynamically inserting values into a sqlite table doesn't work (Code attached)

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to dynamically insert values into the sqlite table but it is not working. Can you please look at below code and point out if I'm making any mistakes.

```
import sqlite3


def Create_Connection(db_file):

    Conn = None

    try:
        Conn = sqlite3.Connection(db_file)
        print("Connection Established")
    except Exception as E:
        print(E) #LOG THIS
    return Conn

def Enter_Values(Group, Timestamp, URL, Response, StatusCode, Message, IsCriticalError):

    if (Group == 'Google'):
        Query = "INSERT INTO Google(Timestamp, URL, Response, StatusCode, Message, IsCriticalError) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",(
        Timestamp, URL, Response, StatusCode, Message, IsCriticalError)
        print(Query)
        Conn1 = Create_Connection('Urldb.db')
        if Conn1 is not None:
            Cursor = Conn1.cursor()
            Cursor.execute(Query)
            Conn1.commit()


    elif (Group == 'Wikipedia'):
        Query = "INSERT INTO Wikipedia (Timestamp,URL,Response,StatusCode,Message,IsCriticalError) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",(
            Timestamp, URL, Response, StatusCode, Message, IsCriticalError)
        Conn1 = Create_Connection('Urldb.db')
        if Conn1 is not None:
            print('Creating Cursor')
            Cursor = Conn1.cursor()
            Cursor.execute(Query)
            Conn1.commit()
```

The 'Query' variable with the dynamic values amounts to this when I run the code:

```
('INSERT INTO Google(Timestamp, URL, Response, StatusCode, Message, IsCriticalError) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', ('04:38:41', 'https://www.google.com/', 'OK', 200, 'OK', 0))
```

The datatypes I used while creating the table are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (
            Timestamp text,
            URL text,
            Response text,
            StatusCode integer,
            Message Text,
            IsCriticalError integer
            )""".format(Group)
```

I'm using this function in another module. I don't get any errors when I run this, just that data is not added to the database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When using a parameterized query you need 2 arguments to `execute`, try

```
query = """INSERT INTO Wikipedia(Timestamp, URL, Response, StatusCode, Message, IsCriticalError) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"""
params = (Timestamp, URL, Response, StatusCode, Message, IsCriticalError)
Cursor.execute(query, params)
```